# Problems with Factory girl and mongoid

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have this to classes:

```
class User
     ...
has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
     ...
end

class Post
     ...
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

validates :user_ids, presence: true
     ...
end
```

Then I also have this factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

   factory :user do
   end

end


FactoryGirl.define do

   factory :post do
   end

end
```

before I have the validation     validates :user_ids, presence: true, it worked well, but when I added that validation, it signals the error in the form so it is good. but rspec doesn't work:

```
    Mongoid::Errors::Validations:

      message:
        Validation of User failed.
      summary:
        The following errors were found: Customer ids can't be blank
      resolution:
        Try persisting the document with valid data or remove the validations.
```

So I tryed this:

[issue on github but for activerecord](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/369)

[blog post](https://arunsark.wordpress.com/2011/05/18/rails-habtm-in-mongoid-factory-girl/)

and tried this things:

```
factory :post do
  before_create do |post|
    FactoryGirl.build(:user, post: post)
  end
end
```

or

```
before(:create) do |post|
  post.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user, post: post)
end
```

or

```
 before(:create) do |post|
      post.users << FactoryGirl.create(:user, post: post)
    end
```

or

```
users { create_list(:user, 2) }
```

or

users { [create(:user, posts: [])] }

but then I get:

```
 bundle exec rspec spec --colour --format documentation                                                                                                                                                
/Users/toni/.rvm/gems/ruby@my-project/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Comment: There is no method `before_create` in [`FB docs`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Callbacks). But there is `before(:create)`. Are you sure you used the right one?

Comment: thanks, I update the code, the problem still persists

Comment: As far as I know `build` does not persist record to db. Have you tried creating user factory `FactoryGirl.create(:user, post: post)` in `before(:create)` callback?

Comment: Tried now, the same error with stack, i will add the expample

Comment: Also your factories are empty with no relations specified. You might want to create traits or nested factories. Check out [`Associations`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations) chapter in FB docs. There are examples of how to work with has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.